# How to create a communication timeline of a particular person?

Tags: json, xml, user-interface, xslt, communication

## Main Goal

Create a unified timeline of communication (via different modes like SMS, Call logs with recordings, Telegram,etc.) with a particular contact.

#### Requirements

- Create a Conversation UI with sender and receiver differentiation.
- Merge conversations from different platform based on time but color coded based on the platform used.
- Should be able to display text messages, audio recordings, images and possibly videos.
- Navigate to a particular date
- Browse media files

Basically I want to create something like the webUI of Whatsapp but only for a single contact that is stored locally and can be archived on a discs or flash drives.

## Progress so far

- I have exported my SMS and call log to an XML file.
- There is away to export telegram conversation to a JSON file via [this method.](https://www.haykranen.nl/2014/12/02/howto-backup-your-telegram-chats/)
- Have call audio recordings with date and time.

### Question

I have searched multiple sites but haven't found any program or solution for this. Also on the UI front some suggest XSLT is a good method to convert XML data to be displayed as a webpage.

How do I merge them without having to manually merge them together ?

**The main problem I face is how to merge the SMS XML and the telegram JSON messages based on the time, link the audio and other media also time based in-between the messages.**

Also is there anyway I can include a calendar which can help me navigate to a particular date of conversation with the dates with no conversation greyed (similar to blogs, etc).

Is XSLT the best for UI ? Is there a better way I can create a convo view with the XML data? I also need to display/link the media within the same page.

Since this is a webpage, I am sure the browser based search would work for text searches but could I implement a better one for the message alone ?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping people with tangible coding problems/errors. While an interesting problem, your Q is too board and likely to attract opinionated answers, so it fails ( on two categories at least) to be useful here. See https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information for info on re-writing your Q so it might be acceptable on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com . And, yes, given XML inputs, XSLT is a very likely candidate to glue all of this together, but at a very steep learning curve. Good luck.